# How to browse the form errors

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'd like to browse the form errors but I it doesn't work for me.

I tried it without ajax and I this is the error

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") 
in AppBundle:Admin:errors-form.html.twig at line 5.
```

I think that the problem is how to loop this line using twig:

```
    'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form),
```

This is the code

```
protected function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}


public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //..
    } else {

        $view = $this->renderView(
            'AppBundle:Admin:errors-form.html.twig', array(
                'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form),
            )
        );
        $response = new JsonResponse(array(
                'view' => $view,
                'result' => 0,
                'message' => 'Invalid form',
            )
        );
        return $response;

    }


}
```

This is the view returned with JsonResponse in case of errors , but the errors are not displayed, **but if I put a static text in this view it will appear after submit**

```
<div id="error">

    {% for error in data %}

        {{ error }}

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: can you post an exapmle of what `getErrorMessages` returns?

Comment: The form is with ajax , in the console I get this error : 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @inaliahgle  I tried it without ajax and I this is the error

   `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") 
    in AppBundle:Admin:errors-form.html.twig at line 5.`

Comment: use {{ error.message }} instead of {{ error }}. i update the answer. it should work for you.

Comment: It must be two {% for %} loop , and I have fixed it like this and now it works good. I have just posted the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be two {% for %}  loop , and I have fixed it like this and now it works good.

```
<div id="error">

    {% for data in data %}
        {% for error in data %}
            {{ error }}<br>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want just get the errors and show them in the twig, No need for the `getErrorMessages`. You could pass the form `$form` to the view:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($form->isValid()) {
    //..
} else {
    $view = $this->renderView(
        'AppBundle:Admin:erreurs-form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form,
        )
    );
    $response = new JsonResponse(array(
            'view' => $view,
            'result' => 0,
            'message' => 'Invalid form',
        )
    );
    return $response;
  }
}
```

and use the built-in `form_errors` in the twig to fetch errors and show them:

```
{% if form_errors(form) %}
<div id="error">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Or could get the errors in the Controller by :

```
$view = $this->renderView(
        'AppBundle:Admin:erreurs-form.html.twig', array(
            'data' => $form->getErrors()
        )
    );
```

and use this to handle it in the twig :

```
<div id="error">
{% for error in data %}
    {{ error.message }}        
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: It wokrs only like this 
`$view = $this->renderView( 'AppBundle:Admin:erreurs-form.html.twig',
                        array('form' => $form->createView(), ));`

and in th view `<div id="error">

             {{ form_errors(form) }}
                {% for children in form.children %}
                    {% if not children.vars.valid %}
                        {{ form_errors(children) }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            
</div>`

But I prefer to not render again this `'form' => $form->createView(),` , I'd like just to return errors

Answer (score 0):

The `getErrors` method only returns the first level of the form which means the form itself and not its children.

You need to provide the boolean argument to have the method search deep in the form: `getErrors(true)`

```
protected function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    // ...

    foreach ($form->getErrors(true) as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    // ...

    return $errors;
}
```

See symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#accessing-form-errors

EDIT

I didn't pay attention to the beginning. The error in you template is due to the following piece of code:

```
foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
    if (!$child->isValid()) {
        $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
    }
}
```

`$this->getErrorMessages($child)` is actually returning an array, not a string. You need to do as follows:

```
foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
    if (!$child->isValid()) {
        foreach ($this->getErrorMessages($child) as $error) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] .= ' '.$error
        }

    }
}
```